# How to get the class name from a typescript annotation

Tags: typescript, annotations

I am using typescript annotations at method level. I would like to be able to get the class or file name from the annotation.

```
const some = (arg: string) => {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      // get class name here <------------------------
      const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
      return result;
    };
  };
};


class Foo(){

  @some("xyz")  
  bar(){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an [instance member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators), the decorator is called with the *prototype of the class*.

```
function some(arg: string) {
  return (targetPrototype: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    const className = targetPrototype.constructor.name;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        console.log(className);
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful in relying on that. Minifying bundlers tend to change object names, which could through off the logic. See this page for more info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#telling_the_constructor_name_of_an_object